# how to fix "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mern, react-fullstack

```
*
```

**> const PORT=8000

> ```
> const express = require('express')
> const {v4:uuidv4}=require('uuid')
> const bcrypt =require('bcrypt')
> const jwt =require('jsonwebtoken')
> const cors=require('cors')
> const {MongoClient}=require('mongodb')
> const { raw } = require('express')
> const uri='mongodb+srv://Adi:Adi@cluster0.djy2w.mongodb.net/Cluster0?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
>
>
> const app=express()
>
> app.use(cors())
> app.use(express.json())
>
> app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
>     res.json('hello')
> })
>
>
>
>
>
> app.get('/user', async (req,res)=>{
>     const client= new MongoClient(uri)
>     const userId=req.query.userId
>     console.log('userid',userId)
>
>
> try{
>     await client.connect()
>     const database=client.db('app-data')
>     const users=database.collection('users')
>     const query = {user_id:userId}
>     const user= await users.findOne(query)
>     console.log('usersss',user)
>    res.send(user)
>
> }catch(err){
>     console.log(err)
>
> }
>
> finally{
>     await client.close()
> }
> })
>
>
> app.post('/signup',async (req,res)=>{
>
>     const client= new MongoClient(uri)
>     const {email,password}=req.body
>
>     const generateeduderId=uuidv4();
>     const hashedpassword= await bcrypt.hash(password,10)
>
>     try{
>         await client.connect()
>         const database=client.db('app-data')
>         const users= database.collection('users')
>
>       const existingUser= await users.findOne({email})
>
>       if(existingUser){
>           return res.status(409).send('User already exists... Please Login')
>                     }
>
>
>       const sanitizedEmail=email.toLowerCase()
>       const data={
>           user_id:generateeduderId,
>           email:sanitizedEmail,
>           hashed_password:hashedpassword
>                 }
>
>
>       const inserteduser = await users.insertOne(data)
>       const token=jwt.sign(inserteduser,sanitizedEmail,{
>           expiresIn:60*24,
>       })
>
>         res.status(201).json({token,userId:generateeduderId })
>     }
>     
>     catch(err){
>         console.log(err)
>
>     }
>
>
> })
>
>
>
>
>
>
> app.post('/login',async(req,res)=>{
>     const client= new MongoClient(uri)
>     const {email,password}=req.body
>     
>     try{
>         await client.connect()
>         const database=client.db('app-data')
>        const users= database.collection('users')
>          const user=await users.findOne({email})
>
>
>          const correctpassword= await bcrypt.compare(password,user.hashed_password)
>
>          if(user && correctpassword){ 
>             const token=jwt.sign(user,email,{
>                 expiresIn:60*24
>             })
>             res.status(201).json({token,userId:user.user_id})
>          }
>           
>          res.status(400).send('Invalid Credentials')
>     }
>     catch(err){
>         console.log(err)
>     }
>
>
> })
>
>
>
>
>
> app.get('/users', async(req,res)=>{
>    const client= new MongoClient(uri)
>
>    try{
>        await client.connect()
>         const database=client.db('app-data')
>        const users= database.collection('users')
>
>       const returnedUsers=await users.find().toArray()
>       res.send(returnedUsers)
>
>
>    }
>    finally{
>        await client.close()
>    }
> })
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
> app.put('/user', async(req,res)=>{
>     const client= new MongoClient(uri)
>     const formData=req.body.formData
>
>     console.log(formData)
>
>   try{
>  
>     await client.connect()
>     const database=client.db('app-data')
>     
>     const users=database.collection('users')
>     const query= {user_id:formData.user_id}
>
>
>     const updateDocument={
>         $set:{
>             first_name:formData.first_name,
>             dob_day:formData.dob_day,
>             dob_month:formData.dob_month,
>             dob_year:formData.dob_year,
>             show_gender:formData.show_gender,
>             gender_identity:formData.gender_identity,
>             gender_interest:formData.gender_interest,
>             url:formData.url,
>             about:formData.about,
>             matches:formData.matches
>
>         },
>     }
>
>    const inserteduser= await users.updateOne(query,updateDocument)
>    res.send(inserteduser)
>   }
>   finally{
>       await client.close()
>   }
>
> })
>
>
>
> app.listen(PORT,()=>{
>     console.log(`server running on port ${PORT}`)
> })
>
>
>
>
> ***
>
>     error
>     server running on port 8000
>     Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
>     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
>     at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)
>         at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\aadar\Desktop\chat\seayo\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:776:10)
>        at ServerResponse.send
> (C:\Users\aadar\Desktop\chat\seayo\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
>        at C:\Users\aadar\Desktop\chat\seayo\server\index.js:120:26 {
>      code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
>     }
> ```
>
> ---

- 

Comment: Please give a [mre] with consistent formatting. But usually the error means you tried to respond twice to the same request, check the logical flow.

Comment: Where is line 120?

Comment: You are returning the response twice. 
"res.status" is being called twice in "/users" get api

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the response twice. "res.status" is being called twice in "/users" get api.

As the response is already sent with the headers, it throws an error that you are not allowed to set headers twice.